Dropdown doesn't work, i.createPopper is not a function
I am developing a website with Symfony 7 that uses Bootstrap 5.3. Everything works fine so far, except for dropdowns. I have the following dropdown in my code:
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown link
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>

When I click on it, it doesn't show anything and log this error in the console:

Uncaught TypeError: i.createPopper is not a function

I installed Bootstrap using AssetMapper. Here is my importmap.php file:
<?PHP
return [
    'app' => [
        'path' => './assets/app.js',
        'entrypoint' => true,
    ],
    '@hotwired/stimulus' => [
        'version' => '3.2.2',
    ],
    '@symfony/stimulus-bundle' => [
        'path' => './vendor/symfony/stimulus-bundle/assets/dist/loader.js',
    ],
    '@hotwired/turbo' => [
        'version' => '7.3.0',
    ],
    '@popperjs/core' => [
        'version' => '2.11.8',
    ],
    'bootstrap' => [
        'version' => '5.3.3',
    ],
    'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' => [
        'version' => '5.3.3',
        'type' => 'css',
    ],
    'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js' => [
        'version' => '5.3.3',
    ],
    'bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css' => [
        'version' => '1.11.3',
        'type' => 'css',
    ],
    '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css' => [
        'version' => '6.7.2',
        'type' => 'css',
    ]
];

And my app.js:
import './bootstrap.js';
/*
 * Welcome to your app's main JavaScript file!
 *
 * This file will be included onto the page via the importmap() Twig function,
 * which should already be in your base.html.twig.
 */
import './styles/app.css';

// Import Popper.js
import '@popperjs/core';

// Import everything related to Bootstrap
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js';
import 'bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css';

// Import font awesome
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css';

console.log('This log comes from assets/app.js - welcome to AssetMapper! ');


I found the solution. We need to use bootstrap.bundle.min.js.
importmap.php:
'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' => [
    'version' => '5.3.3',
],

app.js:
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js';

